# Left align, and center an inline image inside a container

Tags: html, image, css

What I am trying to do is have an image centered, and then another image inline with it that is aligned to the left. I have tried searching and have found nothing thats works right. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <header>
   <div>
   <a href="index.html">
   <img src="left.png" border="0" width="174" height="350" />
   <img class="center" src="center.png" border="0" width="700" height="350" />
   </a>
   </div>
```

CSS

```
html 
{
    min-height:100%;
}
body 
{
    background-color: #9CF;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
body,td,th 
{
    font-size: large;
    margin: 3% 5% 3% 5%;
}
.container 
{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    padding: 6px;
}
.linkbg 
{
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFF; 
    text-align:center;
}
.dashboard
{
    text-align:right;
}
ul
{
    background-color: #0099CC;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    padding-top:6px;
    padding-bottom:6px;
    opacity:0.7;
}
li
{
    display:inline;
}
.nava:link,.nava:visited
{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:black;
    background-color:##0099CC;
    text-align:center;
    padding:6px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.nava:hover,.nava:active
{
    background-color: #00FFFF;
}
img 
{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9;
}

.center
{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another way to do this:

- Add `text-align: center;` to the container.
- Apply `position: absolute; left: 0;` to the "left" image (you should
  add a class for it).
- You can remove all the CSS for `.container img`.

The left image will not affect the position of the other image because it's absolutely positioned. The other image will be centered exactly in the container.

Comment: Thank you so much.This works, since that works. Is there anyway to have the images shrink, like keep aspect ratio when you are viewing on smaller screen, instead of having it overlap.

Comment: Sure, you can add something like `width: 20%` to each image. As long as you specify a percentage, it will resize with the container and never overlap. If this solves your problem, please "accept" my answer by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

you can try using the below given technique

```
<img style="margin:0px auto;display:block" src="Image URL Here"/>
```

for a full review you can check the below link
http://bloggingfear.blogspot.in/2012/11/how-to-center-image-using-html-5-code.html

Answer (score 1):

You have problem in this code

```
img 
{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9;
}
```

just change this with

```
img 
{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

moreover the style you want to apply on it can simply be added without complications that you added.

Here is the demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/mastermindw/9qAL6/7/

Comment: That actually fixed one issue I had, but it doesn't give me the effect I am looking for. I want an image to be left and one center in same row.

Comment: I have updated jsfiddle, it will work for you inshaAllah. http://jsfiddle.net/mastermindw/9qAL6/7/

Comment: Okay, this is super close. I need the 700x350 to be dead center of page, its close, but a little off center to the right. The left 174x350 is perfect, and one other thin I cant get right. I need them to stay next to each other no matter what the screen size is. Thanks for the help so far.

Answer (score 0):

this is the way I makes a picture load in the middle of a page

```
<img src="..." alt=".." style="margin:0px auto;display:block" />
```